# Getting data from a column of a dataset to populate items of a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a dataset in my visual studio project which is connected to a Microsoft Acess datebase. I want to populate the values of a particular column in the table into the items of a combo box (i.e. dropdown box). For this I created a table adapter called "empnames" and a method "GetDataByName()" which selects only the column which is required.

First I tried this 
  
comboBox1.ItemsSource = empnames.GetDataByName().ToString(); 

For this I get the letters in the table name as different items of the combo box.  For example if the table name is emp_data, I get 8 items in combobox i.e. 'e','m','p','d','a','t','a'. 
Can you please help me to get proper result.

Thanks

Code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
SampleDataSetTableAdapters.Emp_dataTableAdapter empnames = new SampleDataSetTableAdapters.Emp_dataTableAdapter();
comboBox1.ItemsSource = empnames.GetDataByName();
}
```

This is the code for method to populate the combobox items. The GetDataByName() is designed using table adapter query configuration wizard. Return type is data table.

Comment: You're assigning a string to the ItemSource - you should assign a collection. Are you sure you're getting 8 items? Post some code.

Comment: How do I create a collection from the column values?

Comment: Well what *exactly* does GetDataByName() return? List? It may just be a case of removing the ToString() extension depending on your answer to my first question.

Comment: GetDataByName() is a table adapter method which returns a single column from the query.

Comment: private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
SampleDataSetTableAdapters.Emp_dataTableAdapter empnames = new SampleDataSetTableAdapters.Emp_dataTableAdapter();
comboBox1.ItemsSource = empnames.GetDataByName();
        }
This is the code for method to populate the combobox items.
The GetDataByName() is designed using table adapter query configuration wizard.

Comment: @Abhilash, don't post code in the comments, edit your question instead

Comment: And what is the return type of GetDataByName?

Comment: @Abhilash - edit your original question to include the GetDataByName method code! The return type isn't data table. Either that, or your OP is incorrect.

Comment: I am unable to view the code for that method as I created it using table adapter query configuration wizard.

Comment: See Thomas Levesque's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the `DataTable` to the `ItemsSource`, and set `DisplayMemberPath` to the name of the column you want to show.

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = empnames.GetDataByName();
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; // assuming there is a "Name" column
```